# What is the difference between Power Apps and Field Service

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I know Power Apps is a member of Power Platform, and Field Service is a member of the Dynamics 356 family product.

But is Field Service a built-on-top application of Power Apps?

How do they correlate vice-versa

I want to know if i can customize Field Service by using Power Apps.

Comment: Field Service is an add-on of Dynamics 365 (Customer Engagement family) and this Dynamics 365 is built on Power Apps/Dataverse (in particular is model-driven app)

Answer (score 0):

PowerPlatform more like a family of products connected to Microsoft Dataverse.

Dynamics CRM is a Model-Driven App.

Model-Driven Apps are web apps connected to the Dataverse as well as Canvas App.

When you buy Field Service licenses (or Sales, etc...), you add to your Dataverse a bunch of new Tables, Processes and Model-Driven Apps.

As the base tables of Dataverse, you can totally customize Field Service tables and add your own custom processes (workflows, plugins, powerautomates, etc...).

So to answers your question, yes you can customize Field Service using Power Apps.